# Does the dimension table support concurrent writing?

Tags: data-warehouse, dolphindb

I have created a dimension table in `dolphindb` database. Now I want to write the data in it concurrently. Does a dimension table support the concurrent writing?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the version 1.30.13 , a new configuration of enableConcurrentDimensionalTableWrite is added, which allows the dimension table to do parallel writing.